# Prevent multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to fetch content from server via ajax on load. But in a particular case i have a few links that are exactly same. In such case how do i prevent my code from making multiple server/ajax calls to the same url but replace different div's.

```
jQuery('.js-ajaxfill').each(function(i){
    var _this = jQuery(this);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: _this.data('href'),
        success: function( data ) {
            _this.children('div').replaceWith(data);
        },
        error   : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            _this.html("");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to store objects with 2 properties, `LinkURL` and `DivID`. Whenever you make an ajax call, check whether that link already exist in the Array,

**If it is not available** : make the call,get the result, Add the entry to the Array with the corresponding the `DivID`.

**If the item is already in the array** :  (that means we already made call to this url), get the `DivID` of that entry and get content of that Div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use response caching

```
var ResponseCache = {};
jQuery('.js-ajaxfill').each(function(i){
    var _this = jQuery(this);
    if(!ResponseCache[_this.data('href')]){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: _this.data('href'),
            success: function( data ) {
                 ResponseCache[_this.data('href')]=data;
                _this.children('div').replaceWith(data);
            },
            error   : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                _this.html("");
            }
        });
    }else{
        _this.children('div').replaceWith(ResponseCache[_this.data('href')]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajaxfillRequests = {};

jQuery('.js-ajaxfill').each(function () {
    var _this = jQuery(this),
        url = _this.data('href');

    // make a new request only if none has been made to this URL, save the XHR
    if (!(url in ajaxfillRequests)) {
        ajaxfillRequests[url] = jQuery.get(url);
    }

    // add one set of callbacks per processed item to the XHR object
    ajaxfillRequests[url]
        .done(function (data) {
            _this.children('div').replaceWith(data);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            _this.html("");
        });
});
```

This works because of the way jQuery XHR objects are designed. They are [*promises*](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), which means you can add as many callbacks to them as you like. It also means you can add callbacks whenever you like, it's not necessary to add callbacks in the options of the actual `.ajax()` call.

Once such a promise is fulfilled (i.e., the request succeeded) or rejected (i.e., the HTTP request failed) all appropriate callbacks are called.

This means you can add an individual callback for every `.js-ajaxfill` element you have and still make the actual request only once.

Comment: this will not replace multiple div's

Comment: @WebDeveloper That's the way I understood your question. (*"prevent my code from making multiple server/ajax calls to the same url"*). If you only want to prevent multiple network round-trips just use appropriate caching headers and the browser will use its cache for requests to the same URL.

Comment: The calls are made in quick succession so no case of server cache header

Comment: @WebDeveloper Yes. Let your server send caching headers (`Cache-Control`) and the browser will not make the same request twice. No need to change your JavaScript at all.

Comment: sorry if i am making a noob question but just to clarify myself the second call is made even before i response for the first one. will it still work

Comment: @WebDeveloper See modified answer.

Comment: @WebDeveloper I've tested it, it works. Consider adding a more detailed error description than "doesn't work".

Comment: Hm, okay. Why don't you set up a jsFiddle that shows this behavior. Because I definitely tested it, and it definitely works. So there must be something else wrong. I'm sure we'll find it.

Comment: thanks Tomalak for all the help... let me setup a fiddle and update you